# oracle setup new database on oracle linux 5

Tags: linux, oracle, ssh

I've installed oracle11g on **OracleLinux5**, in order to replicate a customers oracle configuration. I only have access via SSH and the web interface, and i need to setup the character set,and a few other parameters NLS, N-NLS.
Of what i understand it seems i cannot alter the parameters of the current database, and i would need to install a new one and set the parameters at creation time. Is this true ?
If yes, how could i do this via  **SSH** ?

thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to reinstall the software. You only need to create a new database if you got the information wrong the first time (and delete the old one probably).

You can create a new database using dbca. You can find more information here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897/install.htm#ADMQS0232

You can do this over ssh. If you are on windows, download [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/). You will need to install and download Xming and Xming fonts. The public domain version of these are enough.

Comment: Just to add, after installing you could use something like putty to connect to the server with X11 Forwarding. This will allow you to run DBCA remotely though SSH